# How to add a new parameter in the app.request from twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I want to add a new parameter in the `app.request` from twig.

I have tried with this but am not getting the result I expected:

```
{% set app.request.query.set('script') = false %}
```

Comment: I think `{% do app.request.query.set('script', false) %}` should work.

Comment: what your needed with the new request query?

Comment: You shouldn't add request parameter from twig. Can you please explain the need to do it from twig?

Answer (score 0):

You should **never** change the request object in a Twig template. I don't think it's even possible actually.

If you just want to add a parameter and use it in the current template, just do something like this:

```
{% set parameters = app.request.query.all()|merge({'script': false}) %}
```